# django url pattern "The empty path didn't match any of these."

Tags: python, django

I am trying to configure static files for django v2.2.1 following this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

In `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Project directory:

[image]

But I'm getting this error when running `localhost:8000`

[image]

I've been scratching my head for too long.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see anything wrong with the above. The root path `/` is not supposed to hold any content, or respond with anything specific, because you didn't configure it to. Try accessing `localhost:8000/admin`

Comment: You don't actually have a route that matches... if you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/no_picture.png` you'll likely get a response... but you don't have any view that returns anything for the root

Comment: In your `urlpatterns`, there should be one explicity entry like `path('', view_function(), name='home'),
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the picture as your response you will have to visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/no_picture.png`

If you want access to the admin page visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`

You aren't receiving any response on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` because you haven't defined a view for that url pattern.

To write a Hello World view for example check out [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) from django documentation.